# Does capitrano conflict with docker？

Tags: docker

## Does capitrano conflict with d0cker?

I an new to docker， I want to find a easy way to deploy rails project when something has changed in that project. Someone told me that if you use docker, you must not use capitrano again. And this is my question?
Does capitrano conflict with d0cker?

thx all.